# PDF of a Continuous Random Variable Proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

$V$ is the speed uniformly distributed between $[40, 100]$. With a distance of $200$ km and uniform linear motion, the pdf of the time traveled was given as:
$$
f_T(t) =\begin{cases} 
     \frac{10}{3} \frac{1}{t^2} & 2\leq t\leq 5\\
   \end{cases}
$$

What I understand is that since the speed (V) has uniform linear motion then: $V = \frac{Distance}{Time}$. I tried to solve for the pdf of $t$. Where I used $f(t) = \frac{d}{V} = \frac{10}3t$
$$ f_T(t) = \int_2^5  \,\frac{10}3t\,dt$$ But all this results to $\frac{10}3 \ln(\frac{5}2)$

What is the correct $f(t)$ to use in this case? I feel I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can try:

- $V$ is uniformly distributed on $[40,100]$
- For $40 \le v \le 100$ find the cdf $F_V(v)=P(V \le v)$ in terms of $v$
- $T=\frac{200}{V}$ which is a decreasing function
- So for $2 \le t \le 5$ find an expression for $P(T \ge t)$ in terms of $t$
- Then find the cdf $F_T(t)= P(T \le t)$ in terms of $t$
- Then find the density $f_T(t)$

If you do each step correctly, you should get $F_V(v)=\frac{v-40}{60}$ and $P(T \ge t)= \frac{10}{3t}-\frac23$ and $F_T(t)=\frac53 -\frac{10}{3t}$ and $f_T(t)=\frac{10}{3t^2}$ on the interval of interest

Comment: Thanks I got it! Correct me if am wrong but, essentially this approach works like some reverse method from the CDF to the PDF instead of the usual way around. My only question is why is that the expression from F(v) results to P(T>t) and not P(T<t)?

Comment: Nvm I understand it now since its due to the fact that T is a decreasing function.